# Malformed results getting saved in JSON

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch API response and save it to a JSON file. Due to malformed JSON file I am not able to print the output. I am new to Python. Can someone point out what's the correct way.

"content" is a text file containing the following quotes.

```
Order growth in France, the U.K. and Spain was more than offset by lower ordersfrom Switzerland, Finland, Norway and Germany.Lastly, you can see orders in the AMEA region were up 1%.
Strong growth in Industrial Automation was supplemented by slight growth inElectrification and Motion, while Robotics & Discrete Automation faced a tough market.
Lower orders from China and South Korea were offset bypositive developments in India, Japan, Singapore and UAE.Looking more closely at China, developments were mixed.
……….
```

## Code begins here

```
import requests

url = "https:...d7b74&q={}"

payload = {}
headers= {}

for i in range(0,len(content)):
response = requests.request("GET", url.format(content[i]), headers=headers, data = payload)
data=json.loads(response.text)
if os.path.exists("data.json"):
    with open("data.json", 'r') as f:
        all_data = json.load(f)
else:
    all_data = []
all_data.append(data)
with open("data.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f)
```

The Output JSON Looks like this: I guess there is an issue with the indentation in which the JSON is getting saved

```
{
"query": "Cash flow from operating activities was $670 million, up 19%.ABB's regional and country order trends for the third quarter are illustrated on Slide 4.",
"topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Operating environment",
    "score": 0.171772957
},
"intents": [{
    "intent": "Operating environment",
    "score": 0.171772957
}, {
    "intent": "Competitive advantage",
    "score": 0.121084154
}, {
    "intent": "Operational efficiency",
    "score": 0.06508337
}, {
    "intent": "Value Proposition",
    "score": 0.0280118641
}, {
    "intent": "Critical resources",
    "score": 0.00757621927
}, {
    "intent": "None",
    "score": 0.00240731682
}],
"entities": []
}{
"query": "Specifically, in the United States, our largest market, Electrification order growth was robust apart from large orders, whichhad a tough comparison base.",
"topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Competitive advantage",
    "score": 0.252725929
},
"intents": [{
    "intent": "Competitive advantage",
    "score": 0.252725929
}, {
    "intent": "Operating environment",
    "score": 0.06572733
}, {
    "intent": "Operational efficiency",
    "score": 0.0437437519
}, {
    "intent": "Value Proposition",
    "score": 0.0294999164
}, {
    "intent": "Critical resources",
    "score": 0.00545410533
}, {
    "intent": "None",
    "score": 0.00353605044
}],
"entities": []
```

Comment: I think you should use mode `"a+"`.

Comment: Yes That's Correct. Feeling so Silly. Thanks

Comment: Even after that There is a problem with how the JSON is getting saved. I am getting a syntax error with the JSON.

Comment: Just writing a series of JSON objects into a file one after the other does not create properly JSON-formatted document. You need to put all the objects in some kind of overall container object, such as a list. i.e. a comma-delimited series of objects enclosed by`[` and `]`.

Comment: @martineau. Thanks for your comment. That's what I got. I have re-formatted my question.

Comment: @martineau Can you check now. Thanks

Comment: Unless you post a [mre] so I can see what the responses are, I can't really help you further…however…I _might_ be able to figure it out if you show what's ending up in the data.json file now.

Comment: Hi @martineau. Could you please check now?

Answer (score 0):

When writing, you can use 'w+' or 'a+'. w+ is for writing and it will erase the previous content of the file, on the other hand, a+ stands for append, and will add the content to the end of the existing file.

In this case you should use a+.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved.

I just followed what was told in the comments by @martineau.

```
import requests

url = "https:...7ebdd7b74&q={}"

payload = {}
headers= {}
if os.path.exists("responsefile.json"):
    os.remove("responsefile.json")
for i in range(0,len(content)):
    response = requests.request("GET", url.format(content[i]), headers=headers, data = payload)
    data=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    if os.path.exists("responsefile.json"):
        with open("responsefile.json", 'r') as f:
            old_data = json.load(f)
    else:
        all_data = []
    all_data.append(data)
    with open("responsefile.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(all_data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the code in the answer you posted following the advice I gave in comments may work, it's extremely inefficient because it reads and write the file many times, as well as deletes it first if it already exists — all of which is unnecessary.

Here's a much more succinct version that only (over)writes the file once, yet *should* accomplish exactly the same thing. Note that I am unable test it myself since you never posted a minimal reproducible example — so there might be something minor wrong with it.

```
import requests

url = "https:...7ebdd7b74&q={}"

payload = {}
headers= {}

all_data = []
for quote in content:
    response = requests.request("GET", url.format(quote), headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    all_data.append(data)

with open("responsefile.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f)
```